# Describing the language formed by a particular grammar

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

- **G → G B ⏐ G N ⏐ ε**
- **B  → ( E )**
- **E  → E ( E ) ⏐ ε**
- **N  → ( L ]**
- **L  → L E ⏐ L (⏐ ε**

For this grammar, the prompt asks to describe in  the language that this grammar describes and builds.

I got to the point of first trying at defining the language each one builds but the recursiveness of this grammar threw me off a bit.

I'm kind of stuck, thus far I tried to start with let's say **N** and try to describe it as generating a left paren followed by a left paren and right bracket.

I could really use some direction on where to go with this.

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  Have you searched this site to look for similar questions that might be helpful?  In particular, please make sure to read http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/50456/755 and http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/10605/755 and http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/60109/755.

Comment: Enumerate all strings up to some size, say ten. Look for patterns.

Comment: @Raphael Just saw your comment! Think I got it in terms of thinking how the strings are formed.

Now just thinking about how to create the parse tree for the right derivation of the string ((]() I got the tree for the left, probably crawl around and look for more resources.

Comment: Also determining if the grammar itself is LL or LR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a simple description for the language generated by this grammar, but here's what happens.

1. From $E$ we have the productions $E\rightarrow E(E)\mid\epsilon$. The first few strings generated from $E$ are: 
   $$\begin{align}
   \epsilon &\quad E\Rightarrow\epsilon\\
   (\:) &\quad E\Rightarrow E(E)\stackrel{*}{\Rightarrow}(\:)\\
   (\:)(\:) &\quad E\Rightarrow E(E)\Rightarrow E(E)(E)\stackrel{*}{\Rightarrow}(\:)(\:)\\
   (\:(\:)\:) &\quad E\Rightarrow E(E)\Rightarrow E(E(E))\stackrel{*}{\Rightarrow}(\:(\:)\:)
   \end{align}$$
   It's not too hard to show inductively that $E$ generates all and only the strings of balanced parentheses, i.e., the strings over $\{(\;,\, )\}$ that could appear in a legal arithmetic expression. Let $\mathcal{B}$ denote this language.
2. From the production $B\rightarrow (E)$ we see that $B\stackrel{*}{\Rightarrow}(\mathcal{B})$, namely any string of balanced parentheses enclosed in $(\,)$.
3. From the productions $L\rightarrow LE\mid L\:(\:\mid\epsilon$. It's not too hard to see that $L$ generates all strings over $\{E,\,\,(\,\}$. Call this language $\mathcal{L}$. In simple terms, $L$ generates all strings of balanced parentheses interleaved with an arbitrary number of left parens.
4. From $N\rightarrow\,(\,L\,]$ we see that, similarly to step (2), we have $N\stackrel{*}{\Rightarrow}(\,\mathcal{L}\,]$
5. Finally, it's not too hard to see that from the productions $G\rightarrow GB\mid GN\mid\epsilon$, that $G$ generates all strings over $\{B,N\}$, so we have that the language of this grammar will generate all strings made from the concatenation of terms of the form $(\mathcal{B})$ and $\:(\mathcal{L}\:]$ in any order.

For example, a string generated by the grammar is $((\:)(\:)((\:]\,(((\:)(\:)))$, where I've separated the $N$ and $B$ substrings for clarity.

As I said at the start, not pretty.

Comment: This approach can be used to derive a specification for the language that is simpler, at least. For instance, $\mathcal{G} = \mathrm{SEQ}\bigl( \mathtt{(}\mathcal{B}\mathtt{)} \cup \mathtt{(}\mathrm{SEQ}(\mathcal{B} \cup \{\mathtt{(}\})\mathtt{]} \bigr)$.

Comment: @Rick Decker thank you so much! Our professor went over class the other day and it started to click but the way you explained it makes more intuitive sense and a lot clearer than she explained in class.

I got some learning to do!

Comment: @RicardoRigaroni. You're welcome. By the way, welcome to the site!